# Fetching Data from Core Data between epoch timestamps is inconsistent

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I am fetching records from Core Data between two timestamps which represent the start and end of the day using the following predicate:

```
let timeStampPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "timestamp >= %f AND timestamp < %f", startTimeStamp, endTimeStamp)
```

The above predicate works perfectly until **11:59:00 PM**, but any record saved after it, like at **11:59:22 PM** are not returned by the predicate.

**Example:**

Records in Core Data :

Record 1:

```
Timestamp: 1631816962.0 
Date: 2021-09-16 18:29:22 +0000 // My TimeZone is +0530
Challenge ID: 1 
Value: 100.0
```

Record 2:

```
Timestamp: 1631816902.0
Date: 2021-09-16 18:28:22 +0000 // My TimeZone is +0530
Challenge ID: 1
Value: 100.0
```

Passed Values to the predicate:

```
startTimeStamp : 1631730600.0 // 2021-09-15 18:30:00 +0000 

endTimeStamp : 1631817000.0 // 2021-09-16 18:30:00 +0000
```

When I execute the predicate only 1 record is returned which is inserted before **11:59:00 PM**

Can anyone help me understand what's happening or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Enable Core Data verbose logging (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/12306343/1187415)

Comment: @MartinR The SQLite query also shows only 1 returned row :( . Can I structure the predicate in any other way ?

Comment: In your sample, the Challenge Id is the same, you don't care about unicity about it, right? Could you do the request with no predicate and then try to apply your predicate to the result? Maybe piece by piece (in 2 predicates, not only the first one), and check why the second record is not valid?

Comment: @Larme I do care about the challenge ID, since I could be querying for a different challenge. Filtering after fetching all data for a challenge ID is working as expected. Kudos for mentioning it.

Comment: Did you filter using NSPredicate & `evaluate()` with the same predicate that failed before?

Comment: You need to debug, you can see https://pastebin.com/ffhTFAVe which are sample tests to run and try to understand which one has unexpected result...

Comment: @Larme Thanks I'll create a new paste bin with results

Comment: @Larme Ran all the test [pastebin.com/QdfBMCPp](https://pastebin.com/QdfBMCPp). Still the same output of skipping any record between 11:59:00 PM 11:59:59 PM

Comment: @Larme I was again debugging this issue and if I pull back the end time by 60 seconds (from 12:00AM to 11:59 PM) then the predicate works perfectly :   https://pastebin.com/Y1UrHVz3

Comment: Using this predicate also works `NSPredicate(format: "%K BETWEEN {%f, %f}", argumentArray: [#keyPath(CaloriesData.timestamp), startTimeStamp, endTimeStamp])` but it also includes the records entered @ 12AM for the next day

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure as what's causing the problem as the Predicate seems to be fine.

To rule out all possibilities I even tried using `NSComparisonPredicate` but still the same result.

As @Larme suggested in the comments, I tried filtering the data once I get all back from Core Data.

Did a simple `filter(_:)` on the fetched array.This approach is working as expected.

If anyone can confirm if `filter` is the way to go on an array which won't contain more than 300 records.

**Update 1:**

If I use the **BETWEEN** Predicate it kinda works :

`let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K BETWEEN {%f, %f}", argumentArray: [#keyPath(CD_Model.timestamp), startTimeStamp, endTimeStamp])`

But it also includes records entered for the next day @ 12 AM which kinda defeats the purpose. I could maybe filter for records after fetching the records but I feel that may create it own edge cases

Comment: Well, it's still better to filter in the request than the result, because if you fetch 400k elements to get after filtering only 2, it's memory/optimization issue...